# Homology of the diagonal sequence of 3x3 commutative diagram of modules

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology, spectral-sequences, coherent-sheaves

Suppose we have modules $M_{i,j}$ over a commutative ring $R$ (or members of some abelian category, like quasi-coherent sheaves of modules),
and suppose that we have a 3x3 commutative diagram, where every row and column is a *short exact* sequence (ommitting the extremal zeros for simplicity).

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
M_{0,0} @>>> M_{1,0} @>>> M_{2,0}\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
M_{0,1} @>>> M_{1,1} @>>> M_{2,1}\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
M_{0,2} @>>> M_{1,2} @>>> M_{2,2}\\
\end{CD}

By composing arrows, we obtain the (not necessarily exact) diagonal sequence
\begin{equation}\label{1}
0 \to M_{0,0} \xrightarrow{\delta_0} M_{1,1} \xrightarrow{\delta_1} M_{2,2} \to 0\tag{$\Delta$}
\end{equation}

**Question**: What is the homology of the diagonal sequence $(\Delta)$ at the location $M_{1,1}$?

It is easy to see that $\delta_0$ is injective, $\delta_1$ is surjective, and $\delta_1\circ\delta_0 = 0$.
So it remains to calculate the homology of the middle term.

I am sure that there is a relevant spectral sequence or some other tool from homological algebra, but I don't know how to approach this question.

Comment: At first glance it looks like it should be $M_{2,0} \oplus M_{0,2}$.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Thanks for the observation. That is consistent with the examples I have tried, but I don't know how to go about proving it for examples I care about. It seems like it would come from the total complex of a double complex, but I'm not sure how to execute it.

Comment: If $H$ is the relevant homology, then I think a diagram chase should let you construct maps $H \to M_{2,0}$ and $M_{2,0} \to H$, and perhaps show that $M_{2,0} \to H \to M_{2,0}$ is the identity. Oh, and any answer has to treat $M_{2,0}$ and $M_{0,2}$ the same, by symmetry of the diagram.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri ah, yes you are right. This should do it. Thanks!